# Bootstrap Fullcalendar addClass in popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullcalendar

I just want to addclass name for bootstrap fullcalendar popover. I have tried the `$(".popover").addClass('fc-ctpopover');` in below script in many places. Its not working for this code.

Comment for further clarification.

**$(".popover").addClass('fc-ctpopover');**

My expected output `<div class="popover fc-ctpopover"`>

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();
    var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        height: 600,
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,

        select: function(start, end, allDay) {
            var title = prompt('Event Title:');
            if (title) {
                calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
                        title: title,
                        start: start,
                        end: end,
                        allDay: allDay,
                        title: 'the title',
                        content: function() {
                            return $("#popoverContent").html();
                        },
                        template: popTemplate,
                        placement: 'left',
                        html: 'true',
                        trigger: 'click',
                        animation: 'true',
                        container: 'body'
                    },
                    true
                );
            }
            calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
        },

        eventRender: function(event, element) {
            element.popover({
                title: element.find('.fc-title, .fc-list-item-title').html() + '<span class="popover-title"><a data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" class="close">&times</a></span>',
                placement: 'top',
                html: true,
                trigger: 'manual',
                animation: true,
                container: 'body',
                content: function() {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        element.popover('hide');
                    }, 20000);
                    return $('#popover-content').html();

                }

            }).on("mouseenter", function() {
            $(".popover").addClass('fc-ctpopover');  
                var _this = this;
                $(this).popover("show");
                $(".popover").on("mouseleave", function() {
                    $(_this).popover('hide');
                });
                $(".close").click(function(e) {
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    $(this).trigger("click");
                });

            }).on("mouseleave", function() {
                var _this = this;
                setTimeout(function() {
                    if (!$(".popover:hover").length) {
                        $(_this).popover("hide");
                    }
                }, 300);
                $(".close").click(function(e) {
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    $(this).trigger("click");
                });

            });

        },
        eventAfterRender: function(event, element) {
            $(".popover").remove();
            element.popover('hide');

        },

        eventClick: function(event, element, view) {
            //element.popover('hide');
            $('#modalTitle').html(event.title);
            $('#modalBody').html(event.description);
            $('#eventUrl').attr('href', event.url);
            $('#calendarModal').modal();
        },

       

        editable: true,
        events: [{
                title: 'All Day Event',
                start: new Date(y, m, 1),
                description: 'This is a cool event'
            }, {
                title: 'Long Event',
                url: 'http://stackoverflow.com',
                start: new Date(y, m, d - 5),
                end: new Date(y, m, d - 2)
            }, {
                title: "Conference",
                color: "#F6BB42",
                start: "2019-06-04",
                end: "2019-06-05"
            }, {
                id: 999,
                title: 'Repeating Event',
                start: new Date(y, m, d - 3, 16, 0),
                allDay: false
            }, {
                id: 999,
                title: 'Repeating Event',
                color: '#FB6E52',
                start: new Date(y, m, d + 4, 16, 0),
                allDay: false
            }, {
                title: 'Meeting',
                color: "#DA4453",
                start: new Date(y, m, d, 10, 30),
                allDay: false
            }, {
                title: 'Lunch',
                start: new Date(y, m, d, 12, 0),
                end: new Date(y, m, d, 14, 0),
                allDay: false
            }

        ]
    });
    var popoverElement;

});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.2.6/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.3/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.1.1/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="calendar"/>
```

Comment: `<div class="popover fc-ctpopover">` how can I add the class `fc-ctpopover`

Comment: As far as I can tell, using the element inspector, the class does get added whenever you move your mouse over the popover. Tested using the latest Chrome browser, with your runnable demo above. Can't see any issues, the class gets added as expected.